# Как эти штуки называются и как их лучше всего добавить на страницу?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу сделать выпадающее меню. Сорри за плохое качество

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Треугольники можно сделать с помощью `border-color`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 4px;
}

.triangle {
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="dropdown">
  <span>lorem</span>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>lorem</span>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>lorem</span>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать символы, например этот - `▾`.
А добавлять как угодно, например, при помощи псевдоэлемента:

```css
.arrow::after {
  content: '▾';
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<span class="arrow">Arrow</span>
```